# How to combines 2D mat into a 3D one?

Tags: c++, opencv

Here is my problem, I have 8 mat grayscale images with 100*100,
I would like to combine them together into a 3d matrix like 100*100*8;

Here is my code: (8  mat  are named from `img1` to `img8` with same size 100*100 and pixel value is `double`)

```
int sz[3] = {img1.rows,img1.cols,8};
Mat m(3,sz, CV_8UC1, Scalar::all(0));
m.at<double>(m.rows,m.cols,1)=img1;
```

I think this code can put img1 into the 1st plane of 3d matrix 100*100*8, but then I got a error:

> The type cannot convert from MAT to double.

How could I fix this problem?

Comment: Why do you need this 3d image? OpenCV support for N-dimensional images isn't that great. You can do this but it's not very easy to work with. Are you sure a `std::vector<Mat1b>` isn't enough?

Comment: Wow could you tell me how to use std::vector<Mat1b>? I need this because I would like to make 10 mat a loop. like :    for (i=0;i<10;i++){ do something with Mat (:,:,i);}.....Is there any ways to do this?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32733223/5008845)

Answer (score -1):

You have to convert the double type matirces into uchar matrices first, which can be done as follows:

```
cv::Mat img1u;
img1.convertTo(img1u);
m.at<double>(m.rows,m.cols,1)=img1u;
```