# What is right and efficient way to copy Mat 2D array to part of other ndim Mat array?

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I've made a crop from image:

```
cv::Rect ROI(x, y, WINDOW_SIZE, WINDOW_SIZE);
cv::Mat P = I(ROI);
```

And I have 3D array with dims like (2, 100, 100), and I want to copy P(which is a 2d array with (11, 11) dims) to, let's say, (1,11:22,11:22) position.

How do I do that?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/32733223/5008845